# Using session without declaring session in Application.cfm

Tags: session, coldfusion, application.cfm

I need to use session without declaring session in application.cfm in coldfusion.

Comment: you should be using application.cfc by now but why can't you use `<cfapplication name="..." sessionmanagement="Yes">`?

Comment: lot of places still stuck on application.cfm.  it is one of those " if it ain't broke, so don't fix it" situations.

Comment: _"I need to use session without declaring session in application.cfm in coldfusion."_ - **no you don't**. You might _think_ you do, but unless you have some rare situation, you can (and should) use Application.cfm or Application.cfc as appropriate. (And if you do have that rare situation, as Travis says, [cfapplication](http://cfdocs.org/cfapplication) with a consistent name is what you need.)

Comment: With few details it sounds like a new application if they are trying to sort out session management

Comment: Yep, wouldn't be surprised if someone has simply said "modern apps don't use App.cfm", and they've misunderstood that.

Comment: Who up voted this? Lol

Comment: This question makes very little sense.  What are you trying to accomplish that you wouldn't declare a session?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I think, It is possible to  declare session variable with empty value on page and can be used where you want to use.

Comment: You can't use sessions without first enabling them, which requires setting sessionmanagement to true, either in cfapplication or Application.cfc, as already stated above.

Comment: Also, this gets a -1 for being a very bad example - `SELECT *` should list specific columns, username should be a parameter (i.e. [cfqueryparam](http://cfdocs.org/cfqueryparam)), `#getdata.recordcount# gt 0` has both unnecessary hashes and redundant comparison, and finally you're attempting to copy a variable's value, but instead assigning its name as a string. Oh, and there's no output within the cfoutput tags, which makes them unnecessary noise.

Comment: It's nice to see a ColdFusion shop out there but I wouldn't be promoting your site/services with examples like this.

Comment: -1. Not sure why this answer was accepted. It contains multiple errors and does not actually work...

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought of NOT doing session but do a client variable?

```
<CFQUERY NAME="getLogin" datasource="#reqest.dsn#">
     SELECT int_pk_id
     FROM tbl_users
     WHERE var_email = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" value="#FORM.Email#">
</CFQUERY>
<CFSET CLIENT.User_ID = "#getLogin.int_pk_id#">
```